# SharePoint compatibility issue in IE11

Tags: sharepoint-online, internet-explorer

I have created a regular Site Page which works fine in all browser except IE11. The content of that Site Page is not showing in IE11. **After F12 and change Document Mode to IE=Edge Under Emulation all content are visible.**

I make too much research onto this and find one solution i.e. adding `meta` tag, that works for me but that one is not a regular Site Page of SharePoint.

Please! add some suggestion that **How I add** `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>` **to regular site page without disturbing master page?**

> **I got no solution of this question till 12 days. Now, Whom should I reward bounty? Please! let me know, Thanks.**

Comment: Not possible to my knowledge. You may have to look into the incompatibilities of why your content isn't rendering in IE11. Is it a webpart? Is it a custom page? Is it an ASP.NET embedded app?

Comment: In content editor web part, I am adding URL of a HTML5 page and SharePoint forces IE to use lower version i.e. IE10.

Comment: As in an iFrame?

Comment: Nope, there is no IFrame.

Comment: **I got no solution of this answer till 12 days. Now Who will I assign bounty. Please! let me know**

Comment: Sorry to say but now this bounty has been closed. Now you cannot assign bounty to any one, also it will not be refund to your account. See [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

Comment: **So there is no answer to this question, should I accept it?**

Comment: No, If you are not satisfied with answer or any answer does not solved your problem then there is no meaning of accepting the answer. Because it will misguide to the future users and lead them to the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a console.log() JS command? I ran into this once where In IE 11, the console is not defined until you bring up the console and refresh the page. It will cause JS errors and the page will not load correctly.

This below might help you if that is the case.

```
if( (window['console'] !== undefined) ){
    console.log( text );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your master pages are probably default IIS and are either http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" or "IE=10"

If you must continue as-is then [use an .aspx HTML file which loads with a meta tag that instructs IE to render in EDGE mode](https://gist.github.com/purtuga/95ce7b50b22adc545c79#file-ie-aspx), and your XHTML page in an iframe. Your master page is probably already IE can only set the rendering engine once per page load. Once set it cannot be changed and thus all pages loaded through an iframe are forced to EDGE mode.

- That said, I suggest you use `<!doctype html>` if at all possible.
- [Microsoft recommends this too: starting with IE11, edge mode is the preferred document mode; it represents the highest support for modern standards available to the browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx).
- `<!doctype html>` will trigger the HTML5 document type declaration to enable edge mode.
- As for trying to figure out how to trigger a specific browser mode, there is a long list of considerations, not least of which includes if you try and search for an answer you will find old information that does not reflect the latest upgrades or patches to IE11 modes.

The rulesets are not easy to debug as it is affected by IIS .net patch version, web server settings, user modes, update of compatibility modes (both from Microsoft and via policy in your organization), IE Compatibility View Settings, HTML document type, ordering and precedence of any other HTML code, iframe or cross-site links, Browser security policy via Group Policy Object and Content Security Policy, CSS media queries, and any JavaScript routines that may affect those as shims or frameworks that make those assumptions.

I would try `<!doctype html>`, look to see what is no longer rendering, take a search at that over at http://caniuse.com/ or scan with Microsoft's tool to check for old depreciated tags over at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/staticscan/

You may also enjoy - or start crying - reading [What happens in Quirks Mode?](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) - the choice is yours!

Comment: After adding `script` code in `SharePoint:ScriptBlock` and `meta` tag in `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">`. `IFrame` not visible in **SharePoint site**. Reference `Github URL` mention in answer.

Comment: I want to make this work on **SharePoint regular site page**. Otherwise it works perfectly in simple ASPX page. Where I added HTML5 content.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue in my SharePoint Hosted App. I added below lines in my `<head>` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

I have found some interesting thing. I hope this help you.

Follow below steps.

- Go to site setting
- Go to Site Collection Administration
- Go to Search Engine Optimization
- Select **Include these meta tags in pages**

Here you are allowed to add `<meta>` tags for SEO purpose. And it will add tags to all pages while rendering. So Add your `<meta>` tag here.

[Source](http://www.n8d.at/blog/how-to-add-viewport-meta-without-editing-the-master-page/)

How I tested whether it will work or not?

- I created simple Site Page. Checked the html source of the page by
  using "View Page Source" option of browser.
- I searched for `<meta>` tag with name **`viewport`**. It was not
  found on the page.
- Then I added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
  initial-scale=1.0"/>` in SEO tag
- Again I checked the source code and this tag was present on page.

Hopefully it should work. Let me know whether it solved your query

Comment: 1. I don't know the location of master page.

Comment: 2. I don't want to disturb the settings of the master page.

Comment: Got your point. Give me some time. I am trying at my end.

Comment: **Invalid custom meta value. This field may only contain valid meta XHtml elements.** After adding `meta` tag at this place Search Engine Optimization. I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a .html file on my sitepages. but adding all the tags in the world did not help me, it opens in chrome ok, and in IE11 on my local machine ok. but in sharepoint IE11 does not work, but opening from sharepoint chrome does.

I thought uploading the file as .aspx will force IE11 to render the html. but this blog article looked too advanced for me to solve.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25442.web-sensitive-files-and-sharepoint-sharepoint-2010-2013-and-2016.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SP 2016 On Prem:

I had a similar issue where things worked great in Chrome but kept failing in IE11.  FileReader wouldn't load.  When I manually changed the content to Edge it would work, but the next time I loaded the page it would revert back to 9 and my code failed.

I found that in my Master Page (seattle.html) there was an entry for `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` .

I modified that to be `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` and now everything is working fine in IE 11.